¿Is it more efficient to use 'off' or 'one' in jQuery for handling unique events?
Problem Description:
When editing a record in a web application, an undesired behavior is observed where the guardarEditContrato() function is executed multiple times with each click on the save button, despite it should only be executed once per record edit. This suggests improper handling of click events in jQuery, which can result in suboptimal performance and undesired behavior in the application. The main question is whether it is more efficient to use the off method to remove the event and then re-bind it, or if it would be better to use jQuery's one method to ensure that the contract save function is only executed once per record edit.
$(document).off("click", "#btnGuardarEditContrato").on("click", "#btnGuardarEditContrato", function () {
    guardarEditContrato(contrato_id);
});


They're not doing the same thing, it makes no sense to compare performance.

.off().on() removes any old handlers before adding the new one, but then the event can be handled multiple times.

The equivalent of .one() is to call .off() inside the event handler.

just an opinion, you can use a variable like busy to prevent calling the function again when busy === true. leave the event listener alone.
